# Threading not working properly in vb.net.. i have used threading for quering database

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, db2

My windows application went to "not responding state" when query is running for long time and any UI operation was performed.
So i went for Threading concept. But when performing Database operation inside the Thread.start() method. It gives error like "windows application has stopped working"

My code:

```
 Dim Newthread As New Thread(AddressOf test)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1;Password=pwd;Persist Security Info=True;User ID="";Data Source="";dbalias="";"
End Sub


Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)      Handles Button5.Click
    strSQL = "query"
    Newthread.Start(strSQL)
End Sub

Function test(ByVal strSQL As String)
    connection = New OleDbConnection(CON_STRING)
    connection.Open()
    Dim selectCMD As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, connection)
    Dim custDA As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
    custDA.SelectCommand = selectCMD
    selectCMD.CommandTimeout = 0
    Dim custDS As DataSet = New DataSet()
    custDA.Fill(custDS)
    Dim chk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(chk)
    chk.HeaderText = "Select Row"
    chk.Name = "Select row"
    DataGridView1.DataSource = custDS.Tables(0)
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
End Function
```

The **error is occuring in the line 'custDA.Fill(custDS)**'

Error - **windows application has stopped working**

Can anyone pls help me...

Comment: Did you mean `New Thread(AddressOf StartThread)` instead of `New Thread(AddressOf test)`?

Comment: Also, in `StartThread`, you are using `CON_STRING` which appears to be undefined.

Comment: before i posted wrongly..now i corrected it..

Comment: You cannot update the UI from your thread.  This is a restriction in .NET, Java, and many other UI toolkits.

Comment: wat can i do for it..How to change the code?...

Comment: You could always do what they did with AJAX, and just have the UI periodically tag the system and get an update.  I have also found that sometimes, you need to do an Infinite Loop (with waiting) to process the information and set a clause that will cause the loop to interrupt when done with the processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of managing a thread yourself, look at backgroundworker.

```
Dim bw As New Backgroundworker
bw.RunWorkerAsync
```

In the 'DoWork' Event handler of the backgroundworker, implement your database download functionality. In the 'RunWorkerCompleted' event handler of the backgroundworker update your UI.